# How could i make a custom view like this in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-tablayout

**Required Custom View** 
[image: Required Custom view]

Hello, I am trying to design a custom tablayout like above.
I have tried using custom view with three-sided border but that's not exactly like above image.Can anyone help, please...

So far I have done as following image,but that's not exactly like the intended one.

[image: my custom view]

Comment: better use tablayout and make it custom

Comment: i have added my current view to the question.Please suggest me about how could i make it exactly like the first image.

Comment: Instead of using background rectangle shape with 3 sides of red color, use rectangle shape with 3 sides of red color and 1 side of grey color shape background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for the record, I have done this using recyclerview instead of a tablayout.Using a custom view with recyclerview viewholder gives me more flexibility.Feel free to notify me if anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your style.xml create a new style for your tab and add like below

```
   <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
   <item name="tabBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and apply this style to your TabLayout will resolve your issue

Comment: Could you update the xml code of your **Tablayout** ..once I successfully used this method.